# Find all the unit vectors $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ that make an angle of $\pi / 4$ with $(0,1,1)$ and $\pi /3$ with $(1,0,0)$ - explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Find all the unit vectors $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ that make an angle of $\pi / 4$ with $(0,1,1)$ and $\pi /3$ with $(1,0,0)$.

I had a couple question with regards to my final solution and interpretation of the solution.

To solve for the set of vectors we use the relationship:

$$\frac{x \cdot y}{\|x\|\|y\|} = \cos(\theta)$$

Where $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2,y_3)$. In my case i will be letting the $y$ vector represent the respective given vector above.The value of $\theta$ is a constant with regards to which ever angle I'm using.

Rearranging this and rewriting things I can set up a system of linear equations.

$$\begin{array}\ 
x_1 + 0 + 0  = \frac{1}{2} \\
0 + x_2 + x_3 = 1 \\
\end{array}$$

Which can be turned into a matrix form:

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 
\end{array}\right]$$

Solving I get the expression:

$$x = \left(\frac{1}{2}, 1, 0\right) + x_{3}(0,-1,1)$$

If I let $x_{3} = 0$ this is still not a unit vector once I perform the necessary operations (taking the norm) on it.

So either I did something wrong in my calculation or I'm not interpreting it correctly.

The second question I had was what happens if we don't assume $x$ is a unit vector? Assuming it was a unit vector helped with the algebra immensely, but if we don't do that I see a big mess occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some consultation with greater minds, I've been informed that my process was correct. What needs to be noted is that

$$x = \left(\tfrac{1}{2}, 1, 0\right) + x_{3}(0,-1,1)$$

is a set of solutions to the system of equations. But we need a specific set of solutions. That is we need to find the value of $x_{3}$  that satisfies:

$$1 = \|x\| = \bigl\| (\tfrac{1}{2},1,0) + x_{3}(0,-1,1) \bigr\|$$

After some algebra we find $$x_{3} = \frac{1 \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{2}$$

will give unit vectors. Which can be verified by letting $x_3$ be either the sum or difference doing such will give solutions:

$$x_{+} = \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}, \frac{1}{2} +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)\ \\ \text{and} \\  x_{-} = \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}, \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)$$

and then calculating the norm to the vectors above.

Comment: This looks good. Two comments: (1) it's easier to write equations with the norm-squared so that there are no radicals, and (2) make sure to finish the problem (what are the two vectors when you plug in the scalar $x_3$?)

Comment: Thanks for the input.